# Is it posible to make a if not?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is it posible to make a if not statement with initers?

```
if (Main.gold >= 400) {
        System.out.println("Kun en Elver/Orc er stærk nok til dette/Du har ikke guld nok.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.

```
if (!(Main.gold >= 400)) { // code }
```

also this works:

```
if (Main.gold < 400) { // code }
```

placing a `!` in front of a boolean statement in `java` gives the logical `not` you are looking for.  You can alternatively use the logical opposite as in the second example:

i.e. `not (x >= 5)` is the same as `x < 5`

Answer (score 0):

Sure! The equivalent code is:

```
if (! (Main.gold < 400))
```

or even you can do:

```
if (!! (Main.gold >= 400))
```

But I'm not sure why you would do this as it will lose some readability.